# Recursion step doesn't update output

Tags: python, recursion

I have a problem with the recursion. The function I wrote should recursively generate and return a list of pairs, called `chain`. The breaking condition is when the pair, `(remainder, quotient)` already belongs to the `chain`-list, then stop iterating and return the list. Instead of completing, the recursion just blows up, raising a `RecursionError`. The list doesn't update and contains only a single term, so the breaking condition is not executed. I don't understand why...

How should I proper implement the recursive step to make the list update?

```
def proper_long_division(a, b):
    """a < b"""
    chain = []

    block_size = len(str(b)) - len(str(a))

    a_new_str = str(a) + '0' * block_size
    a_new = int(a_new_str)
    if a_new < b:
        a_new = int(a_new_str + '0')

    quotient = a_new // b
    remainder = a_new - b * quotient

    print(remainder)    
    #print(chain)
    
    # breaking condition <--- ! 
    if (remainder, quotient) in chain:
        return chain

    # next step
    chain.append((remainder, quotient))
    chain.extend(proper_long_division(remainder, b))
 
    return chain

try:
    a = proper_long_division(78, 91)    
    print(a)
except RecursionError:
    print('boom')
```

Here a an example of recursion which (should) follows the same structure but the returned list is updated. I don't know why one code works while the other does not.

```
import random

random.seed(1701)

def recursion():
    nrs = []
    # breaking condition
    if (r := random.random()) > .5:
        return nrs
    # update
    nrs.append(r)
    # recursive step
    nrs.extend(recursion())
    return nrs

a = recursion()
print(a)
# [0.4919374389681155, 0.4654907396198952]
```

Comment: `chain = []` creates a new list each time.

Comment: You need to create a nonlocal copy of chain that you pass to a nested function which performs the recursion. Or a global list, but that's poor design.

Comment: thanks for your advices. Mmm I quite sure that the recursion pattern works because I used it several time in analogous situations and that's why I am a bit confused. Furthermore how would you explained the case with the other breaking condition? `if (39, 1) == (remainder, quotient): return chain` In that case I got the list

Comment: 1. You create a new list `chain = []`. 2. You check if `(remainder, quotient)` are in the empty list - of course they are not. 3. You store `(remainder, quotient)` in the empty list. 4. You repeat recursively (goto step 1).

Comment: `if (39, 1) == (remainder, quotient)` works because you are not checking if they are in the list. You are just checking their values.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp I agree with your steps... and I guess that steps 1., 2. and 3. I got them + the body of the program make sense (double checked). So the problem is 4. I played around with the recursive step but I always get back a list with an element. How can I fix this? I really don't see it, sorry

Comment: @Mad Physicist thanks a lot! I used a wrapper to fix the problem... I thought that there could be an alternative solution without operating directly on the memory address of the list. Does make sense to say that it was wrong to "query" the list while was under-construction?

Comment: @cards. In python, everything is a reference (pointer in C-speak). Your mistake was initializing a local copy of the list in every recursive call and expecting it to be pointing to the one initialized in the outer call, which it will never be. A global or nonlocal variable allows you to point to the same memory location with the same name.

Comment: I've gone ahead and posted an answer. Your second example is clearly a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter `proper_long_division`, the first thing you do is `chain = []`. That means that the local variable `chain` refers to a new empty list. Then you do some algebra, which does not affect `chain`, and check `if (remainder, quotient) in chain:`. Clearly this will *always* be `False`, since `chain` was and has remained empty.

The next line, `chain.append((remainder, quotient))` runs just fine, but remember that only this call to `proper_long_division` has a reference to it.

Now you call `chain.extend(proper_long_division(remainder, b))`. You seem to expect that the recursive call will be able to check and modify `chain`. However, the object referred to by `chain` in a given call of `proper_long_division` is only visible within that call.

To fix that, you can use a piece of shared memory that any invocation of the recursive function can see. You *could* use a global variable, but that would make the function have unpredictable behavior since anyone could modify the list. A better way would be to use a nested function that has access to a list in the enclosing scope:

```
def proper_long_division(a, b):
    """a < b"""
    chain = {}

    def nested(a, b):
        while a < b:
            a *= 10
        quotient = a // b
        remainder = a - b * quotient

        key = (remainder, quotient)
        if key in chain:
            return chain

        # next step
        chain[key] = None
        nested(remainder, b)
 
    nested(a, b)
    return list(chain.keys())
```

A couple of suggested changes are showcased above. Multiplication by 10 is the same as padding with a zero to the right, so you don't need to play games with strings. Lookup in a hashtable is much faster than a list. Since ordering is important, you can't use a `set`. Instead, I turned `chain` into a `dict`, which is ordered as of python 3.6, and used only the keys for lookup. The values all refer to the singleton None.

The second example does not match the structure of the first in the one way that matters: you do not use `nrs` as part of your exit criterion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it's clear. I was looking for a "single-function" solution but I realized that makes no sense. [and for the advises:)]